# void is an invalid type for the variable deleteLine

Tags: java, алгоритм

Написал программу которая удаляет определенную строку из файла,но что-то не пашет

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Search {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        public void deleteLine(int index){
        try{
        File file = new File("Original File location");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
        File temp = new File("New File location");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(temp);
        String holder;
            for (int i=0;i<index;i++){
            writer.println(reader.nextLine());
        }
        holder=reader.nextLine();
        while (reader.hasNextLine()==true){
        writer.println(reader.nextLine());
    }
        writer.flush();
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
        if (!file.delete()){
    System.out.println("Can't delete file");
    return;
}

if (!temp.renameTo(file)){
    System.out.println("Can't rename file");

    }
}
catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("File not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вылезает ошибка:void is an invalid type for the variable deleteLine.

И заодно хочу спросить:хороший ли это способ удаления строки?

Comment: и  да,если что я - дурак

Comment: у тебя метод delete line в методе main, один метод не может быть в другом, компилятор банально ругается